# mysql count and grouping,ordering

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this..

---

```
| name    | product 
---------------------
 | Amy     | Doll
 | Allan   | Bat
 | Bob     | Pen 
 | Charlie | Eraser
 | Charlie | Pencil
 | Charlie | Sharpener
 | Allan   | Ruler
 | Anoop   | Candy
 *******************
```

I want the number of products bought by each customer. Output should be sorted like 1)Number of products bought in desc order and 2) Customers who bought same number of products should be sorted alphabetically.

Output :

```
*******************
 | name     | number 
--------------------
 | Charlie  | 3             
 | Allan    | 2               
 | Amy      | 1
 | Anoop    | 1
 | Bob      | 1              
 *******************
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT  name ,   COUNT(*) AS `number`
FROM your_table
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY `number` DESC, name;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/386241)**</kbd>